# Oracle Virtual Box not starting on Mac

Tags: virtualbox

Host: Mac OS Ventura

Guest: Oracle VirutalBox 6.1

After the recent OS upgrade to the Ventura on Mac, I am not able to start my virtual box. It used to work perfectly before the upgrade. I have tried other versions of virtual box, such as 7.0, but I am still getting the following error.

Any help would be appreciated .

Thanks.

===================

The virtual machine 'Oracle Linux 9' has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code 1 (0x1).

Result Code:
NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component:
MachineWrap
Interface:
IMachine {85632c68-b5bb-4316-a900-5eb28d3413df}

=======================

Answer (score 1):

Mac OSX Ventura doesn't work with VirtualBox 6.X

- download latest 6.X and unpack virtual box 6.X
- run the uninstall virtual box tool  (you need to approve in System > Privacy and Security > allow run the uninstall tool.

Now You need to download the last version VirtualBox 7.x

- after download unpack it
- run installer
- you need to authorize Oracle kernel extensions System > Privacy and Security > allow Oracle Kernel Extension
- Restart

Now Run VirtualBox from Application folder.
Probably you will need to recreate your network adapter in VirtualBox > File > Tools > Network manager